# How to count the number of ads on a website

Tags: beautifulsoup, ads

I've been looking around but can't find anything. Is it possible to scrape and identify the use of ads (and presumably count them for any given site?

As an example [this](https://www.worthofweb.com/website-value/wikipedia.com/) page has 13 ads.

I'm currently using BeautifulSoup to obtain the page

```
            headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
            url = requests.get("https://www.worthofweb.com/website-value/wikipedia.com/")
            response = requests.request(method="GET", url=url, headers=headers, timeout=5)
            response.raise_for_status()

            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
```

The problem is parsing the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider to analyze every element in the DOM and check for standard ad sizes. Here's a list:

https://www.creatopy.com/blog/banner-standard-sizes/

Briefly, get the width/height from the element's style, and see if it matches a standard ad unit size. If so, we can argue it's an ad (false positives possible though).